How to implement async version of TcpStream::connect()?
I am learning async runtime and trying to write a runtime and an async version of TcpStream.
I have finished the accept(), write(), and read(), just by calling the corresponding functions of std::TcpStream and handle the Error:WouldBlocking error (registering it on the Event-Poller).
However, I do not know how to implement the connect(). For the front functions there are already a TcpStream which I can register on the Event-Poller if pending. But for the connect(), there is no such TcpStream if std::TcpStream::connect() pending. Because it merges socket(2) and connect(2) inside.
I look at the source code of Async::connect() in async-io crate, it call the low-level functions (such as socket(2), connect(2)) directly, for different OS. Do I have to do the same thing (which I do not want to)?

I think it would be very nice if the std::net provides a method to split the socket(2) and connect(2) into 2 parts. For example, giving an UnconnectedTcpStream:
pub struct UnconnectedTcpStream {
  pub fd: RawFd,  // get `fd` after creating socket
}

impl UnconnectedTcpStream {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    let fd = os.socket(STREAM);  // socket(2)
    Self { fd }
  }
  pub fn connect(self, addr: Addr) -> Result<TcpStream> {
    os.connect(self.fd, addr)?;  // connect(2)
    Ok(TcpStream { self.fd })
  }
}


'I think it would be very nice' is sadly not really a question, unsure how to react to that. Also, at this point, the question might become too open for SO.

Note that you can use the nix crate to get a safe(r) interface to the functions provided by the OS.

This is quite a task you set for yourself here. There's a reason why async-io and tokio are popular; writing those things yourself is tedious and error-prone.
As you probably know how async works, you are aware that polling a socket and returning Poll::Pending is not hard. The hard part is to detect that the socket is no longer pending and can be polled again.
There are generally two approaches for that:

Spawn a thread that waits for data, synchronously, and then informs the waker
Register some kind of interrupt that gets called when new data arrives

The second solution is highly platform dependent but should perform better, so that's why async-io and similar choose that path. One of the goals of async networking is to eliminate the spawn-one-thread-per-connection problem, which is a major overhead that enables certain DDOS attacks.
The first solution might be what you should go for if you just use this as a programming exercise and don't require high performance:

Connect with the normal synchronous api
Split the socket into a read and write part
Spawn a thread that reads data from the read part
Put the read data into some type of channel, like futures-channel or crossbeam
Use this channel to read from the socket asynchronously
When writing to the socket, either do the same with another thread, or use a mechanism like spawn_blocking. But always make sure that you do not call blocking functions from an async task, as that would block the entire async runtime!

Good luck!
